# R functions looping

Tags: r

Hi I have a data frame df with 3 columns as follows:

```
 a    b    c
-2    A    G
 1    G    C
 3    T    C
-4    A    G
```

I would like to create a new column `d` which takes the value in `b` if the value in `a` is negative while it takes the value of `c` if positive:

```
 a     b     c    d
-2     A     G    A
 1     G     C    C
 3     T     C    C
-4     A     G    A
```

I wrote something a function like this but it is not working

```
select_allele<-function(x,y){ 
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){   
    if(df$a[i] > 0){
      df$d[i] <- return(y)   
    } else {
      df$d[i] <- return(x)   
    } 
}} 

mapply(select_allele, x=df$b, y=df$c)
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: your code is more complicated than needed. lookup the `ifelse` statement It's very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that while creating `df` you set the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame()`.

```
df$d <-ifelse(df$a>0,df$c,df$b)

#   a b c d
#1 -2 A G A
#2  1 G C C
#3  3 T C C
#4 -4 A G A
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to do this. One way using `sign` function which returns the `sign` of a number

```
df$d <- with(df, ifelse(sign(a) == -1, b, c))
df

#   a b c d
#1 -2 A G A
#2  1 G C C
#3  3 T C C
#4 -4 A G A
```

---

Or with `dplyr` `if_else`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(d = if_else(a < 0, b, c))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(-2L, 1L, 3L, -4L), b = c("A", "G", "T", 
"A"), c = c("G", "C", "C", "G")), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```